# Issue with Navigation Back button appearing in area unable to be clicked

Tags: navigation, swiftui

I am trying to navigate to a View based on a click of a list via NavigationLink.

Below is the code for my detailed view.

The problem is that the back button is all the way at the top of the detail view and is unclickable by the user as seen in the screenshot below the code? How do I resolve this?

```
struct ViewDetails: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var displayDetails: DisplayDetails

    var body: some View { 

        ScrollView {

            GeometryReader { geometry in

                ZStack {

                    if geometry.frame(in: .global).minY <= 0 {

                        Image("header")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                            .offset(y: geometry.frame(in: .global).minY/9)
                            .clipped()

                    } else {

                        Image("header")
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height + geometry.frame(in: .global).minY)
                            .clipped()
                            .offset(y: -geometry.frame(in: .global).minY)

                     }

                }   

            }.frame(height: 400)

            VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                HStack {

                    Image("author")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                        .frame(width: 60, height: 60)
                        .clipped()
                        .cornerRadius(10)

                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {

                        Text("Article by")
                            .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15))
                            .foregroundColor(.gray)

                        Text("John Doe")
                            .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Demibold", size: 15))

                    }

                }.padding(.top, 20)

                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet")
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Bold", size: 30))
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .padding(.top, 10)

                Text("3 min read • 22. November 2019")
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 15))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .padding(.top, 10)

                Text(articleContent)
                    .font(.custom("AvenirNext-Regular", size: 20))
                    .lineLimit(nil)
                    .padding(.top, 30)

            }
            .frame(width: 350)

        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)

            .onAppear(perform: {

                self.displayDetails.showFullScreen.toggle()

            })

    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, with such UI design I don't think default Back button would be usable, even if it worked (it is not due to this `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)`). I would hide default Back button and implement own custom button (say at bottom-left corner of image) navigating back.

Comment: When I create my own back button it gets hidden behind the this view and I can not click it.

Comment: Add it in ZStack *after* images and it will be above, or add it as .overlay to image, etc.

Answer (score 0):

you can set navigationbar displayMode

```
.navigationBarTitle(Text("Painting"),displayMode: .inline)
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
            //Text("testme")
            NavigationLink(destination: p200301navi()){
                Text("testme")
            }
            NavigationLink(destination: p200301nav_solution()){
                          Text("testme2")
                      }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Painting"),displayMode: .inline)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I added that and the result is still the same?

Comment: ,displayMode: .inline)